# Symfony2 - Inject a service into SonataAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, dbal

I'd like to get a db connection from within a SonataAdmin class' `configureFormFields()`

For sure this doesn't work

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $mycnx = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.mycnx_connection');
//...
```

I need it for my extension of `Sonata/UserBundle/Admin/Entity/UserAdmin`

How can I call a service from this class ?

---

The context:

I need to have a choice field (company) whose choices come from an other connection (from a stored procedure).

Comment: You can always get a DB connection in `AdminController` classes. Depending on what you plan to do, this may be a straightforward thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is:

- create a service getting the connection injected to get companies from
- create a custom field
- register it as a service and inject the first service in constructor
- supply the choices to the field

  ```
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
  #...
  ```

Then you'll be able to simply use it from `configureFormFields()` with:

```
->add('company', 'company')
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to use a second dbal connection to supply choices for a form field

You can actually have this a little easier and with less code involved...

---

**Configuration**

Your configuration looks somewhat like this if you already have setup a second connection `doctrine.dbal.mycnx_connection`.

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            mycnx_connection:                       # credentials for 2nd connection
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "%database_host_2%"
                port:     "%database_port_2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name_2%"
                user:     "%database_user_2%"
                password: "%database_password_2%"
                charset:  UTF8

        default_connection:   default
```

Now if you haven't already ... configure a [second entity/document manager](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) that is using this connection:

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine:
    # dbal, ...
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle: ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            company:      # <- setup a second em using the customer connection
                connection:       customer
                mappings:
                    AcmeCompanyBundle: ~

        default_entity_manager:   default
```

---

... this may look like much to this point but it really isn't ... as **everything described above should already be present** in your application if you have a second dbal connection.

I just wanted to make it really obvious for others.

You now have two services available that reflect your two entity-managers:

- `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager.default` ( ... which is aliased to `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` )
- `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager.company`

---

**The Entity Field-Type**

Now all that's left for you to do is use the [entity field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em) and configure it to use the entity-manager using the `company` connection.

<kbd>Acme/YourBundle/Form/Type/YourType.php</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...

$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'AcmeCompanyBundle:Company',
    'em'            => 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager.company',  // <- non-default em here
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('company')
            ->orderBy('company.name', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

That's it ... while you may still want to make your form a service ... you don't have to inject anything.

You don't need to use the `EntityRepository $er` part in `'query_builder'` ... you can just return a QueryBuilder instance if you don't want to create the repository for your companies.

---

### Just my few cents ... happy coding!

Comment: doh ... question from 2012 ... edited 9 hours ago ... accidently switched from `newest` to `active` tab when looking for questions to answer ... haha :D

Comment: Thanks anyway, this is very interesting. But do you think I can use an entity field type for my case (companies fetched from a procedure call, no hands on the related table) ?